# C++ String Prints on Multiple Lines

Tags: c++, visual-studio, output

I've been trying to get into C++, but I can't even get the simplest programming to work for me.

```
while(true) {
    cout << "."
    string in;
    cin >> in;

    cout << "!" << in
}
```

What I was hoping to get:

```
.1
!1
.1 2
!1 2
```

What I actually got:

```
.1
!1
.1 2
!1.2
```

Comment: Although this isn't real code, it is pretty obvious you meant for the first two `cout` statements to be outside the loop. Do that and change `cout << "> " << cmd;` to `cout << "> " << cmd << '\n';` and you are done.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj Perfect. Thank you. I'll try to adapt that to more work later on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cin is a stream that reads from standard input, which may not behave in all the ways you would expect. The extraction operator `>>` reads from cin until whitespace is reached, so `cin >> cmd` only sets cmd equal to the first word in your command. The remaining words are still in cin, so after the program prints

```
> test
```

it loops around again, prompts for input, and reads `test2` from cin instead of allowing you to add something else to the stream.

If you want to read the whole line, use getline.

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <iostream>
using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::getline;

int main() {
  while (true) {
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << "[CMD] > ";
    string cmd;
    // Store the next line, rather than the next word, in cmd
    getline(cin, cmd);

    cout << "> " << cmd;
  }
}
```

This performs as you would expect:

```
[CMD] > test
> test

[CMD] > test test2
> test test2

[CMD] >
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read entire lines, then formatted input directly on `std::cin` is not the way to go. Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Roughly like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  while(true) {
    std::cout << "."
    std::string in;
    getline(std::cin, in);

    std::cout << "!" << in << '\n';
  }
}
```